# Correct login to 'parse' Database

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, parse-platform

I'm trying to create a login page for my application in swift.
I have a view with username and password and two buttons, one for the login and one (signup now) that calls another view in order to create a user.
The login button has to perform a segue to the home page when the login works good, it means that if the username field text or the password field text are empty, the application doesn't have to perform the segue. The problem is that the application calls the home view also if username and password are empty. This is the code:

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var field_username: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var field_password: UITextField!

    var currentUser :PFUser?


    @IBAction func login_clicked(sender: UIButton) {


            login(field_username.text, password: field_password.text)

    }

    func login(username : String, password : String) {

        PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(field_username.text, password: field_password.text) { (user, error) -> Void in
            if user != nil {
                println("[PARSE] Login effettuato con successo")
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueToHome", sender: self)
            } else {
                println("[ERROR] login with error: \(error!.description)")
            }
        }

    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if currentUser != nil {
            println("[Parse] The user \(currentUser!.username!) is already logged in")
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueToHome", sender: self)
        } else {
            println("No user is logged in. \n Login or signup")
        }


    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func returnToLoginView(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I was pretty sure that `self.performSegueWithIdentifier(...)` is executed if user is != from nil.
Anyone can help me to fix this thing? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to perform a conditional segue you can achieve it by creating segue this way:

[image]

After that at your login you can call segue this way:

```
PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(field_username.text, password: field_password.text) { (user, error) -> Void in
        if user != nil {
            println("[PARSE] Login effettuato con successo")
            //segue will perform here
            performSegueWithIdentifier("segueToHome", sender: self)
        } else {
            //Segue will not call here
            println("[ERROR] login with error: \(error!.description)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Happy to help you..:)